# Created New user in Linux, but not able to login in putty or SSH or else

Tags: linux, unix, putty

I am new to Linux, I don't know in-depth things. I created a user from the root account, but I am not able to login as the new user (sampleUser). Here are the commands I used to create new user:

```
useradd  -m  -s  /usr/local/bin/bash  -d  /home/sampleuser   sampleuser
passwd sampleuser  
chown sampleuser.sampleuser sampleuser
chmod 777 sampleuser
```

Comment: Is bash really in /usr/local/bin?  Not that it can't be, but that's a little unusual.  If the shell isn't there, that could prevent login.

Comment: run sudo passwd in your terminal

Comment: Are you able to ssh into it using your original login? Because in a lot of distros, ssh server is off by default and you have to manually bring it up.

Comment: If you aren't a super linux user, you can use shadow package, which provide an interactive command to create new users. The command is adduser and can configure your new user.

Comment: While login are you getting any error? is bash really in `/usr/local/bin` ? or in `/bin/bash` ? add a user like this `useradd` sampleuser then `passwd`and try to login.

Answer (score 1):

as root user, edit /etc/ssh/sshd_conf and see if you have lines starting with AllowUsers or DenyUsers keywords. If you do, add the new user name to the end of one of the AllowUsers lines.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/bin/bash` is a remarkable place for a login shell but possible. Make sure it is there and make sure it is listed in `/etc/shells`. PAM or SSH might require this.

777 permissions on a home directory of a user with a login shell is not safe and could also be checked for valid logins by PAM for instance.